# Drag an image on top of another image with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to drag an image on top of another image at any position. The problem is that Draggable Widget returns the Widget back to initial position after I release the touch, also Drag Target only accepts one fixed position. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide us some code so that we can inspect but for instance, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onAccept` parameter of the `Draggable` widget & update the `offset` value of the widget that's passed to your function as an argument:

```dart
Draggable(
  offset: Offset(xFromState, yFromState)
  onAccept: (value) {
    // Do something with the DragTarget value here
  }
)
```